# issue in run mongostat for auth enabled mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I just implemented auth for mongodb, There is  a user ‘admin’
in db ‘admin’ and ‘appadmin’ in db ‘mydb’ all working fine. below
are my db auth settings:

```
use admin
db.auth(‘’, ‘’)
db.getUsers()
[
    {
        "_id" : "admin.admin",
        "user" : "admin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            },
            {
                "role" : "clusterMonitor",
                "db" : "admin"
            }
        ]
    }
]


use mydb
db.auth()
db.getUsers()

    {
        "_id" : "mydb.appadmin",
        "user" : "mydb",
        "db" : "mydb",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "readWrite",
                "db" : "mydb"
            },
            {
                "role" : "userAdmin",
                "db" : "mydb"
            }
        ]
    }
].
```

If I run the following,

```
mongostat --username=admin --password=mypassword  --authenticationDatabase=admin
insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize   res faults qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn     time
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 240.0M 678.0M 91.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    1 11:49:18
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 240.0M 678.0M 91.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    1 11:49:19
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0 240.0M 678.0M 91.0M      0   0|0   0|0   79b    10k    1 11:49:20
```

But when I run

```
* mongostat --username=appadmin --password=mypassword  --authenticationDatabase=mydb

        Failed: not authorized on admin to execute command { serverStatus: 1, recordStats: 0 },
```

So I tried to add role ‘clusterMonitor’ in mydb.

```
db.updateUser(“appadmin”, {roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: “mydb”}, {role: "userAdmin", db: “mydb”}, {role: "clusterMonitor", db: “mydb”}]})
E QUERY    Error: Updating user failed: No role named clusterMonitor@mydb.
```

What is the best way to do mongostat in a auth enabled mongoldb? Please help me to fix the issue or suggest best auth settings.
Note: my mongodb version 3.0.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally I got the solution, I add more roles to admin db,

```
use admin
db.getUsers()

    {
        "_id" : "admin.admin",
        "user" : "admin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            },
            {
                "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            },
            {
                "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            },
            {
                "role" : "clusterAdmin",
                "db" : "admin"
            },
            {
                "role" : "clusterMonitor",
                "db" : "admin"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and  run mongostat --username=admin --password=mypassword  --authenticationDatabase=admin, fix the issues

Comment: It seems `clusterMonitor` is key to running mongostat.

Comment: I don't understand. You mentioned `mongostat` was failing for `appadmin`, but gave a solution for `admin` user? Can you paste the output for `mongostat --username=appadmin --password=mypassword  --authenticationDatabase=mydb`